# Why post is not firing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have razor page

```
<form method="post" >
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="Id" 
           value="@Model.Employee.ID" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.FirstName" 
               name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.Email" 
               name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
               placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.Mobile" 
               name="mobile" id="mobile" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
               placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <br />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
</form>
```

When I post  public void OnPost() not firing ?

Any reason.

```
  public void OnPost()
        {
            var emp = new DTO.Employee();
            emp.EmployeeId = Request.Form["Id"].ToString();
            emp.FirstName = "";
            emp.LastName = "";
            emp.MotherName = "";
            emp.SecondName = "";
            emp.MaterialStatus = "";
            emp.Gender = "";
            emp.ForeignFirstName = "";
            emp.ForeignLastName = "";
            emp.ForeignSecondNamee = "";
            emp.ForeignThirdNamee = "";
            emp.IsDeleted = true;
            emp.Nationality = "";
            emp.NoBrothersAllowed = false;
            emp.ThirdName = "";
            emp.Phone = "";
            emp.PassportNumber = "";
            emp.Mobile = Request.Form["mobile"].ToString();
            emp.Email = Request.Form["Email"].ToString();
            emp.FirstName = Request.Form["name"].ToString();
            //emp.ID = int.Parse(Request.Form["Id"].ToString());
            EmployeeService.Update(emp);
            Response.Redirect("Index1");
        }
```

Comment: Not related to your current issue (which probably ought to have the code that's meant to be posted to as well, e.g. a [mcve]) but [pssst](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) - there's no reason to hide text input controls like that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was trying to form the question properly it was not aloowing me

Comment: Could you please share your cshtml details for onPost?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I did

Comment: Thanks, try the updated solution, it would resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I post public void OnPost() not firing ?

Actually, it will not fire because, ou have binded the form with strongly type model which is `@Model.Employee.ID` so while you are sending request it doesn't found the matched model and you are not getting anything. You should define your model on the page which would resolve your issue.

Correct way should be as following:

**cshtml.cs:**

```
public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
{
    public Employee? Employee { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Employee = new Employee();
        Employee.ID = 1;
        Employee.FirstName = "Test First Name";
        Employee.Email = "TestEmail@email.com";
        Employee.Mobile = "0123456789";
    }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        Employee = new Employee();
        Employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"].ToString());
        Employee.FirstName = Request.Form["FirstName"].ToString();
        Employee.Email = Request.Form["Email"].ToString();
        Employee.Mobile = Request.Form["Mobile"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
    }
```

cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemoApp.Pages.EmployeeModel

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="Id"
           value="@Model.Employee.ID" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.FirstName"
               name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.Email"
               name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
               placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="@Model.Employee.Mobile"
               name="mobile" id="mobile" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
               placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <br />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
</form>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Razor Page Form submit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form)